# Error 450: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment Excel-Vba

Tags: vba, excel, macros, ms-word

Cannot for the life of me figure out why I cannot add a hyperlink to the selected text.

```
oWord.ActiveDocument.Select
With oWord.Selection.Find
    .Text = "Text to Find"
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Execute
End With

oWord.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add _ 
Anchor:=Selection.Range, _ 
Address:=fpath & ProductName & "_" & ExpTitle & "_" & Revision & ".docx", _
TextToDisplay:="Text to Find"
```

Above code selects the 'Text to Find' but gives me an Error 450 when it tries to add the hyperlink. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `oWord` to connect to Word from within Excel which is fine, however both applications have the object `Selection` and in your `Hyperlinks.Add` code the `Anchor` value is not prefixed with `oWord` meaning it is trying to use the Excel `Selection` which is causing the error.

Change the Anchor line to:-

```
Anchor:=oWord.Selection.Range, _
```

Comment: @SiddharthRout Caught me out a bit as there was some useful detail missing from the question that would have helped and when I first tried it in Word natively it worked fine.

Comment: I just visited the question and started typing the answer and then I saw a prompt that "an answer has been posted"... :D

Comment: @Gary Fantastic! Thanks a million. For clarity so I should be referencing my oWord object each time I'm talking about a Word object, and then my other objects should automatically reference the Excel objects?